# What devil fruits and their users that are able to fly?

Tags: one-piece

In the Alabasta Arc, Pell said that there are only 5 known flying devil fruits.

[image: the manga panel with Pell saying the following dialogue:]

> Pell: You're lucky to see this. Only five flying devil fruits are known to exist

What are these "5 known flying devil fruits" and who are their current users?

Apart from the 5 known, did they discover new flying devil fruits?

**Note:** I'm only talking about the "real flying devil fruit". What I mean here by "real" is like Pel who can naturally fly unlike others who uses their creativity in order to "fly", example of this is

> Doflamingo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I did my own research about Flying devil fruits, and *YES! it looks like there are more than 5 "real" flying devil fruits.*

**Zoan**

1. Tori tori no mi, Model: Falcon - Pell
2. Tori tori no mi, Model: Phoenix - Marco
3. Tori tori no mi, Model: Eagle - Buzz (One Piece 3D: Straw Hat Chase)
4. Tori tori no mi, Model: Nue - Toratsugu (One Piece 20th x Kyoto)
5. Mushi mushi no mi, Model: Kabutomushi - Kabu
6. Mushi mushi no mi, Model: Suzumebachi - Bian
7. Ryu ryu no mi, Model: Pteranodon - King

**Paramecia**

1. Fuwa fuwa no mi - Shiki (One Piece Film: Strong World)

**Logia**

1. Gasu gasu no mi - Caesar Clown
2. Moku moku no mi - Smoker

---

**Unknown devil fruit but can be flight-capable**

1. Dragon fruit - Kaido
2. Crow fruit - Karusu

---

**Flying devil fruits because of "Creativity" of user + Surroundings**

These are fruits that can be flight-capable with some creativity of the user on using his devil fruit abilities and his surroundings

1. Ito ito no mi - Doflamingo

   > By attaching string to the clouds
2. Zushi zushi no mi - Issho (aka Fujitora)

   > By lifting the boulder while he is on top of it

---

**Flying devil fruits because of "Creativity" of the user alone**

I separated these fruits because I think there are debatable if real flying devil fruits or not. Listed here utilizes only their creativity in using their devil fruits abilities and not depending on their surroundings. What I mean here is that if you eat these fruits you will not immediately able to fly unlike the "real" ones, you need to think outside the box in order to fly. A great example of this is Gomu gomu no mi - Luffy.

1. Guru guru no mi - Buffalo

   > Spins his hair like a propeller
2. Buki buki no mi - Baby 5

   > Transform to a missile
3. Buku buku no mi - Charlotte Mont-d'Or

   > Able to make books fly and use it as a foothold
4. Gomu gomu no mi - Monkey D. Luffy

   > Using his gear fourth

---

> Pell: You're lucky to see this. Only five flying devil fruits are known to exist

*Maybe* when Pell said this he is only referring to the Tori Tori no mi? After all, we already saw 5 kinds of this fruit, but the other one looks like not able to fly, the Tori tori no mi, Model: Albatros whose current user is Morgans. If this is true then maybe we can see another variant of this fruit that can fly in the future.

*If not, then maybe* the 5 known flying devil fruits are from the big shots like Marco, Kaido and others since these guys are famous in the world of one piece.

*If that is still not the case, then maybe* at the time that Pell said that then there are only 5 flying devil fruits listed in the "book of devil fruits" since we know that this book doesn't contain all the devil fruits as we saw in the Enies Lobby Arc when Kaku and Kalifa eat their *"unknown" devil fruit at that time*

> [image: Unknown Devil Fruit at that time]

---

Sources:

[One Piece Wikia](https://onepiece.fandom.com)

[Youtube Video about flying devil fruits](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QXvr-VBd08g)

Comment: I would add Ace/Sabo's fruit since the way he uses it to propel himself is the same as Baby5 or Luffy and Laffite's power (if it is from a DF).

Answer (score 8):

Nope, there are more than 5 DF users who can fly:

1. Doflamingo, who can fly using his DF by attaching his thread to a cloud
2. Gear 4 Luffy, who can fly using his elasticity according to Doflamingo
3. Marco, who uses his ancient DF to fly and kick Kizaru
4. Shiki, who had a DF called Fuwa Fuwa no Mi
5. Sabo
6. Caesar
7. Smoker
8. Kaidou, who can fly by changing his form using his mythical DF into a dragon

Comment: While this is debatable, I'm afraid this answer contemplates "the real Flying Devil Fruits" with "Devil Fruits that allows a side-effect of flying".

Comment: As per @AkiTanaka said, will you be able to categorize this list to "Flying Devil Fruits" and "Flying Devil Fruits because of creativity of user"? I just want to see if there is actually newly added to the "known 5 flying devil fruit"

Comment: That info (that Pell's statement was on Alabasta arc, which is in the past) is worthy to be mentioned on the answer, not on the comment.

Answer (score 4):

> What are these "5 known flying devil fruits" and who are their current users?

Without the creative ones, means without Smoker, Sabo and so on. Let's see how far we get.

1. the Falcon fruit of Pell
2. the phoenix fruit of Marco
3. the dragon fruit of Kaido
4. the snow fruit of Monet? She is a harpy after all, but could count as creative. (In this case not set yet)
5. ??? (not set yet)

*Now somebody who might have read more chapters than me, might feel free to edit the list.*

> Apart from the 5 known, did they discover new flying devil fruits?

Not directly discovered, but can be created: As it's stated, that there is a "book of devil fruits", only Vegapunks DFs could increase this number. **Meaning: There are and will be only 5 real DF that can fly, without creativity of their user.**

Comment: I don't think smoker is part of the "creative" ones since he only uses his devil fruit powers to fly

Answer (score 1):

Pell was very likely referring to Tori Tori no Mi or Bird Bird Fruit, which has 5 known models so far.

Which are:

- Tori Tori no Mi, Model: Falcon, consumed by Pell.
- Tori Tori no Mi, Model: Phoenix, consumed by Marco.
- Tori Tori no Mi, Model: Albatross, consumed by Morgans.
- Tori Tori no Mi, Model: Eagle (non-canon), consumed by Buzz.
- Tori Tori no Mi, Model: Nue (non-canon), consumed by Toratsugu.

Keeping in mind that Albatrosses are also able to fly, only that Morgan, the current user of the fruit, for some reason isn't able to.

[Source](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Tori_Tori_no_Mi_(Disambiguation))

There's another fruit which also has capability to fly

- Ryu Ryu no Mi, Model: Pteranodon (canon), consumed by King
- Uma Uma no Mi, Model: Pegasus (canon), consumed by Stronger

Though the other flying users so far, using their devil fruit powers with creativity to fly or seem like flying.

- Logia: Most of logia users having elements having small or no mass like Fire or Smoke can't fly distances like a bird, but levitate given the nature of their fruits, with a few exceptions.

  - Moku Moku no Mi, Smoker, levitates
  - Mera Mera no Mi, Ace/Sabo, levitates
  - Goro Goro no Mi, Enel, levitates (translates to thunder but shown lighting , which doesn't go up, but down only, also points to his need for building a flying ship)
  - Yami Yami no Mi, Teach, levitates
  - Pika Pika no Mi, Borsalino (Kizaru), can fly (as light can travel long distances at the fastest speed known in physics, and earth isn't flat but a sphere, and human neurons speed can't keep up to speed of light, so he travels short distances only)
  - Susu Susu no Mi, Karasu, (flying is done using crow forms, to avoid the confusion, his fruit is of logia type of soot, but he transforms that black soot into form of crows, due to his name probably meaning Crow)
  - Uo Uo no Mi, Model:Seiryu (Azure Dragon), Kaidou, (flies by grabbing to flame clouds, not an inherent flying ability)
  - Mori Mori no Mi, Aramaki (Ryokugyu), (flies by transforming his plant like into forms like helicopters or other flying objects)
- Paramecia: There are some Paramecia fruits which can be used creatively to fly or levitate.

  - Gomu Gomu no Mi, Luffy, flies/levitates by creating propulsion by springing his legs at high speeds.
  - Hana Hana no Mi, Nico Robin, can create several arms from her body like a flower and combining them to form wings.
  - Zushi Zushi no Mi, Issho, can levitate by altering the gravity of objects around him
  - Fuwa Fuwa no Mi, Shiki, can levitate using the telekinetic abilities of his fruit
  - Ito Ito no Mi, DoFlamingo, jumps by attaching strings to clouds (like Spider-man)
  - Soru Soru no Mi, Charlotte Linlin (Big Mom), can fly by giving souls to flying objects and using them

There are other characters in the anime who can fly due to their inherent forms, abilities or using technology like

- Monet, form of harpy, with wings and talons (unrelated to her devil fruit)
- King, of race Lunarian who have wings are able to fly (unrelated to his devil fruit)
- Germa using flying suits
- Cipher Pol and Sanji using Moonwalk ability, which is similar to jumping at high speed causing propulsion like in Luffy's case

These are few of the devil fruits and their abilities which I found creative, but there are more devil fruits which are canon and non-canon, and there can be more devil fruits created in future as well, given that devil fruits are the will of the people, as the will of the people change and their surrounding, new devil fruits can be born, like missile fruits, gun fruits and so on.